# iostream GCC errors, converting to boost::filesystem::iostream for Windows

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, iostream

I'm attempting to convert an app written in C++14 for linux/MacOS.  It uses boost::filesystem, but not for certain iostream operations.  For example:

```
boost::filesystem::path file = name;

std::ifstream fin(file.c_str());
```

This code was failing to compile on Windows 10 using MinGW with GCC 6.3 with the following:

> error: no matching function for call to
>   'std::basic_ifstream::basic_ifstream(const value_type*)'
>       std::ifstream fin(file.c_str());

I thought if I could convert the std::ifstream to boost::filesystem::ifstream I could get it to work...  So I changed the code to this:

```
boost::filesystem::path file = name;

boost::filesystem::ifstream fin(file.c_str());
if (!fin)
{
    file = pathToAppData / "files/expansion/assets/resources/basestation/config/mapFiles/racing" / name;

    fin = boost::filesystem::ifstream(file.c_str());
    if (!fin)
        throw std::runtime_error(std::string("Cannot open Anki Overdrive map file ") + file.string() + ".");
}

fin >> (*this);
```

That resulted in this error:

> error: 'const boost::filesystem::basic_ifstream&
>   boost::filesystem::basic_ifstream::operator=(const
>   boost::filesystem::basic_ifstream&) [with charT = char;
>   traits = std::char_traits]' is private within this context
>   fin = boost::filesystem::ifstream(file.c_str());

It looks like I can't re-assigned a boost::filesystem::ifstream once created...  I was able to change that line to the following and it compiled, but I'm wondering if it's the correct way to do it:

```
boost::filesystem::ifstream fin(file.c_str());
```

Bonus question:  Should this code work on linux as well once I get it working?

Comment: What is `name`? Can you just pass that to the `ifstream` constructor instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Windows `boost::filesystem::path::value_type` is `wchar_t`, because Windows paths use strings of 16-bit UTF-16 characters. According to the C++ standard the `std::ifstream` class only has a constructor taking strings of narrow characters. The Visual Studio standard library adds extra constructors to `ifstream` which take wide strings, but the GCC standard library used by MinGW does not have those extra constructors. That means the `const wchar_t*` returned by `file.c_str()` is the wrong type for the constructor argument to `std::ifstream`.

You can convert the `path` to a narrow character string (by calling `file.string()`) and pass that to the `ifstream` constructor, although I don't know if it will work correctly:

```
boost::filesystem::path file = name;
std::ifstream fin(file.string());
```

As you say, the `boost::filesystem::ifstream` is not assignable (before C++11 streams were not movable or assignable, and it appears that the Boost.Filesystem streams haven't been updated). You can simply change you code to re-open a new file using the same stream object, instead of trying to re-assign to it:

```
fin.close();
fin.open(file);
```

(Note that you don't need to call `c_str()` because the `boost::filesystem::ifstream` constructor taks a `path` argument anyway, not a pointer to a string. By calling `c_str()` you just convert the `path` to a string and then it gets converted back to another `path`, which wastes time and memory.)

> Bonus question: Should this code work on linux as well once I get it working?

Yes. On GNU/Linux `filesystem::path::value_type` is `char` and so the original code would have worked fine anyway. The modified code will work on GNU/Linux too.